# Taking input using delimiter in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, delimiter

After taking those values I have to store the values in two different arrays (say x and y)

Comment: Hello. Sorry, but it seems you are missing the point of stackoverflow. It's not a help me write this code service. If you have a specific problem you can ask and everyone will be happy to help.

Comment: I know, I am not asking to write a whole program. I got stuck here at a particular part and I am not sure how It can I proceed from here.

Comment: If you use C++, please do not add C language tag. They are very different languages.

Comment: It looks like your last edit removed all the text of the question except for one line.

Answer (score 3):

So the only error I can immediately see is this

```
float* a = NULL;
a = new(nothrow)float;
```

which should be

```
float* a = new float[count];
```

Your version only allocates enough space for a single float when you really need space for `count` floats.

When you have code that isn't working, and you want to ask a question about it you really should say exactly what happens when you run the code. Doing this will help get you better answers.